# Question on ne que

Tags: grammaire, ne-explétif

In the following sentence:

> La grand guerre ne cessera que mort ne soit vengée.

A direct translation is "The great war will not stop until the death is revenged". However, I do not understand the role of the second *ne* since it would mean "...until the death is not revenged".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nostradamus verses isn't an easy path to to learn French.

The actual text doesn't contain what you wrote but:

> *La grande peste de cité maritime
>
> Ne cessera que mort ne soit vengée
>
> Du juste sang, par pris damne sans crime
>
> De la grand dame par feincte n'outragée.*

The style is obscure, even by 16th century standards but DeepL gives this translation:

The great plague of the maritime city
Will not cease until death is avenged
Of the just blood, by taken damned without crime
Of the great lady by feint not outraged.

The *ne* your question is about is what is called a *ne explétif*.

See [When/why is "ne" used by itself in dependent clauses?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29593/when-why-is-ne-used-by-itself-in-dependent-clauses)

Comment: Why does the *ne* in the last quetrain "De la grand dame par feincte n'outragée" matter?

Comment: The beauty of the French *ne* is that sometimes it is *explétif* and sometimes it is not, not to mention old French could also use a non split negative where *ne* alone could be enough to state a negation. The last verse is non grammatical by current French standards. I believe this *ne* would be replaced by a *non* or *pas* in modern French: *de la grande dame pas outragée (outrée) par la feinte (tromperie)*.

Comment: Is the first *ne* not effective because it is used with *soit* (subjonctif of etre)?

Comment: There is no definitive rule to know if a *ne* is *explétif*. Sometimes, the logic leads to the right interpretation. This verse is missing an implicit word that couldn't be omitted in modern French: *ne cessera **avant** que mort ne soit vengée* or in a less literary way: *ne s'arrêtera pas avant que la mort [ne] [ se ] soit vengée*, i.e. *ne s'arrêtera pas tant que la mort ne se sera pas vengée*.